# Unable to dynamically post imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso

whenever i try to load image from url in my app..only one image is displayed but i want both of the images to be displayed horizontally like in columns...please help me out.i want both the images to be display at the same time one after another.

here's my mainactivity:

```
package com.example.hp.gotcha;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String[] urls;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urls = new String[]{"url1...","url2...",};
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lay = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        Picasso.with(this).load(urls[0]).into(image);
        tr.addView(image, lay);
        table.addView(tr);

        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lay1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ImageView image1 = new ImageView(this);
        Picasso.with(this).load(urls[1]).into(image1);
        tr.addView(image1, lay1);
        table.addView(tr1);    

    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding rows to your TableLayout, so wouldn't that display vertically, not horizontally?

Comment: well even vertical will do...bt only one image is on the screen that's the problem...btw thanks for reply :)

Comment: Without running the code, I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. When you say "one image," are you sure you are using different URLs?

Comment: yes of course....actually first image is getting overlapped by the next one...nd also when i'm trying to do same thing using for loop...nd using urls[i] instead of 0 or 1 ...my app is crashing..

Comment: Can you add your `activity_main.xml` file with an [edit], please?

Comment: hey i got it right....maybe it was just problem with ma emulator...i ran it on my phone it was loading two images...thank u very much for the help i appreciate it.. :) ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your layout xml?

I was able to successfully test your code using this layout, activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="rocks.throw20.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</TableLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Using your exact same code from MainActivity and this is how it looks.

[Loading images into TableRows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6IOp.png)

Comment: hey i got it right....maybe it was just problem with ma emulator...i ran it on my phone it was loading two images...thank u very much .. i appreciate it.. :)